# using GPS with Linux & output only certain data

Tags: linux, gpsd

Hello I am currently using BU-353 S4 USB GPS in my Linux,

the command,

```
cgps -s
```

Output various parameters including,
Time, Latitutde, Longitute, Speed, Heading etc...

is there any way to output only Longitude and Latitude instead of the complete details ?

I have gone through all the available arguments of `cgps` command and as far as I can tell, this command only output the complete table.

Comment: What about reading the NMEA data directly from serial port and parsing [$GPGGA](http://aprs.gids.nl/nmea/#gga)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [awk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWK) to parse [$GPGGA](http://aprs.gids.nl/nmea/#gga) directly. See example below:

```
echo $GPGGA,001038.00,3334.2313457,N,11211.0576940,W,2,04,5.4,354.682,M,-26.574,M,7.0,0138*79 | awk -F"," '{print $3,$5}'
```

would output:

```
3334.2313457 11211.0576940
```

**Update**

Try something like this:

```
awk -F"," '/GGA/ {print $3,$5}' /dev/ttyUSB0
```

This command should read from /dev/ttyUSB0 (substitute with proper one), find lines with GGA and parse them.

Comment: This is exactly what i want , but could you please elaborate your line of code ?

Comment: @Xufyan -F"," defines a field separator, i.e. ',' in our case. '{print $3,$5}' prints fields 3 and 5 i.e. our Longitude and Latitude. First field is $GPGGA ,second - the time and the third one is Latitude according to NMEA. All you have to is to read from USB serial port and find GPGGA lines. See updated answer.

Comment: @Xufyan I've tested it with my GPS receiver and put the final command to my answer. As long as cat /dev/ttyUSB0 is functioning, my script should also work. Learned something new about awk, pipes etc. myself :-)

Comment: Done already , actually i didn't convert from binary to NMEA this is why the issue caused, i had to run this command before proceeding. gpsctl -f -n /dev/ttyUSB0